# memorystore and instances in different regions (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm building a chat app in React Native, and the backend is in Node.JS I'm using GKE to deploy the server code.

I'm using a cloud sql postgresql, connecting with internal IP. This works. I also use a memorystore (redis). Here is the problem.

For autoscaling, I'm planning to get multiple GKE clusters in different regions (for now, europe-west1 and us-central1). I have configured a load balancer with one backend containing all instance groups. I don't know of this is the correct/ideal solution, but it works. The problem lies in the fact that you can only connect to a redis database from an instance within the same region. If i use use-central1 as the region for my memorystore instance, I cannot connect to it through the vm's in the eu-cluster I created.

What is the best solution to overcome this problem? I've created an extra VM in the same region as the redis instance with haproxy configured to use as a reverse proxy to the memorystore, and this way, I can connect to the redis database through all instances, no matter what region they're in. But I don't know if this is the correct solution?

**EDIT:**

I'm using websockets (socket.io) for chat messages. Because I'm planning to use multiple servers, I need a centralized database to store (references to) the socket ID's, so users can send messages to users that are connected to other servers.

I'm thinking redis is the correct solution for a number of reasons:

- I can use socket.io-redis to store the socket ID's on redis
- fast response time
- I don't know about the size of the data stored, but it's definitely not Mb's

I'm using a postgresql database to store other information (like username, passwords), but it seems to me that redis is a far better solution for real time applications.

Comment: Using a proxy is good, but a real answer depends on a lot of information that is not in your question. For example: What are you using MemoryStore/Redis for? What response time is required? How much data is stored? How much data is transferred over the network? Is Redis the correct storage service? This type of question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. You are not presenting a question with a specific problem or issue that can be answered without opinions or generalizations.

Comment: @John Hanley I'll try to change my question. Thank you for your comment. Edit: I've edited my question.

Comment: Honestly your approach looks pretty well. I'm not aware of a better approach because for your case deploying a redis instance in your cluster doesn't seem to be really useful.